I found a code i dont know on my htaccess
I was checking my htaccess code of recent and I saw the code below
<IfModule mime_module>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php8 .phtml
        FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php81 .php
        FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php81 .php8
        FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php81 .phtml
    </IfModule>

I dont know what it means and I'm not sure if deleting it will cause issue on my website
I have not tried anything, I decided to bring it here before doing anything.

Could be the effect of installing php8 or the fastcgi package on that system. Though it is "surprising" that a distributed configuration file get's altered. The code takes care to have all requests to files that end on ".php" and the like get processed by feeding the requested file through the fastcgi engine (so the php compiler and processor).
